# Firefox proxy server for Puppeteer Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, puppeteer

While my setting up my node.js puppeteer proxy server I found little misunderstandings. My software is Linux Mint 19, I run puppeteer on Node.js. All works well when I run my command:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const pptrFirefox = require('puppeteer-firefox');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args:[  '--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://www.whatismyproxy.com/');
    await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'}).then(()=>{console.log("I took screenshot")});

    await browser.close();

})();
```

proxy run on app tor in the system. While my IP is changed and privacy works, google and other websites recognize me as a bot (even without proxy server ON). When I change into "puppeteer-firefox" proxy flags do not work, but I am not recognized as a bot.

My goal is to not be recognized as a bot and run my puppeteer section incognito (in future from Tails linux, through proxy). I am already very excited from your answers :). I ensure you this is only for development purposes. regards to all

Answer (score 1):

Although Puppeteer and Puppeteer-Firefox share the same API, the arguments you send using the `args` arguments are Browser specific.

Firefox doesn't support passing a proxy from the command arguments. But you can create a profile and launch Firefox using that profile. There are many posts explaining how to create a profile and launch Firefox with that profile. [This is one of them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23117/configuring-firefox-to-use-a-proxy-from-the-command-line).

Comment: Alternatively, you could intercept requests in Node.js. This would work with Chrome and Firefox. View the source code of https://github.com/gajus/puppeteer-proxy.

Comment: Cool project @Gajus!